# How is AJAX request handled in JSF 2.0?

Tags: jquery, jsf-2

I was trying something like below --

```
<h:commandButton id="btnOK">
     <f:ajax event="action" execute="@this" render="idHeader"       
listener="#{myBean.actionSubmit()}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

And I want when that ajax request completes, do some processing in the UI.I am using following jQuery code for that :

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $.modal.close();
});
```

But my problem is the jQuery method is not fired at all. I am wondering if JSF ajax submission fires the ajaxComplete event or not??

Comment: I have had some issues with this "success" state in my onevent javascript function. It seems that every browser other than IE has no issue, and re-renders the component after it returns a success state. IE though re-renders AFTER the success state is returned. This is definitely a problem if you're trying to manipulate something in the re-rendered component from your javascript. Every other browser works great though...I have yet to see a work-around for this IE issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard JSF impl doesn't use jQuery API to send ajax requests. JSF uses its own internal API which you can find in the auto-included `jsf.js` file. So the jQuery `jQuery.ajaxComplete()` is never called. It would only be called when jQuery's `$.ajax()` (and its shortcuts `$.get()`, `$.post()`, etc) is being used. Only jQuery based component libraries use them such as PrimeFaces with `<p:commandXxx>` and `<p:ajax>`. For standard JSF `<f:ajax>`, you need to use JSF's own `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent()` handler instead, or the `onevent` attribute of the `<f:ajax>`.

In *your particular case* I think the `onevent` attribute is mose easy:

```
<f:ajax ... onevent="btnOKhandler" />
```

with

```
function btnOKhandler(data) {
    if (data.status == 'success') {
        $.modal.close();
    }
}
```

The `data.status` can have 3 values: `begin`, `complete` and `success`. See also tables 14-4 and 14-3 of the [JSF specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html).

#### See also:

- [Javascript on (before and after) every Ajax-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463177/javascript-on-before-and-after-every-ajax-call/)

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me instead $(document).ajaxComplete();

```
RichFaces.jQuery(document).on( 'ajaxcomplete', function(event, xhr, settings){   
     console.log(event, xhr, settings);
      // event, undefined, undefined
})
```

Comment: This is for RichFaces, not plain JSF!