# Javascript on (before and after) every Ajax-call

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, tinymce

Since I'm working with `TinyMCE` (please don't go into "Primefaces has an editor" or anything similar) I need to execute a small piece of `Javascript` before and after every `Ajax`-call. I'd prefer not to edit every `Ajax`-call for this since there are a lot (and doing so will be bad practice for any future maintenance).

**What would be the most elegant solution to execute `Javascript` pre- and post- any `Ajax`-call on the page?**

Note: I'm using a custom `composite` for the `TinyMCE`-textarea. Any events too this object would also suffice. Though keep in mind that the actual `Ajax`-trigger might be invoked by a totally different object (though could nevertheless rerender the `composite`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`jsf.ajax.addOnEvent`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/jsdocs/symbols/jsf.ajax.html#.addOnEvent) handler.

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
    switch(data.status) {
        case "begin":
            // This is invoked right before ajax request is sent.
            break;

        case "complete":
            // This is invoked right after ajax response is returned.
            break;

        case "success":
            // This is invoked right after successful processing of ajax response and update of HTML DOM.
            // In case you're interested in error handling, use jsf.ajax.addOnError handler.
            break;
    }
});
```

Just put it in a JS file which is included by `<h:outputScript target="head">` in the `<h:body>` of the desired pages. This will ensure that it's loaded *after* JSF's own `jsf.js` containing the `jsf` namespace.

Comment: I ran into an issue using `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent` which I'm not able to solve, can you take a look at it (update on question)?

Comment: Apparently you're not using `<f:ajax>` to fire the ajax call.

Comment: Ok, seems I misinterpreted this function. Thought it would be executed on `actionListeners` too. Will change my code accordingly, thanks again.

Comment: This is not related to whether you use action listeners or not. Just nest a `<f:ajax>` in the command component.

Comment: I'm quite surprised though that you're explicitly asking how to listen on an ajax request, while you're not firing an ajax request at all.

Comment: Ah.. Let's just say it's been a long day. While testing I've removed my `f:ajax` and replaced them with `actionListener`s. Removed my `actionListener`s and replaced them with `f:ajax` once again. Ofcourse your solution is working as planned now!

Comment: There is something I don't quite understand. As far as I know, ajax requests are made by `<f:commandXXX>` components whether they have an `<f:ajax>` nested or not. But the `addOnEvent` handler only works for the ones that explicitly include the `<f:ajax>` tag? Is there a way to add the event for every ajax call, independently of the `<f:ajax>` tag? Thank you very much.

Comment: @gmanjon: There are no other ways than `jsf.ajax` API to create ajax requests in standard JSF. So this answer is fine. Perhaps you had PrimeFaces in mind? It indeed doesn't use standard `jsf.ajax` API, instead it uses jQuery. In this case, head to https://stackoverflow.com/q/27443142

Comment: You're right (as expected xD). All the ones that were not being intercepted were PrimeFaces components. It only doesn't work for `<p:dataScroller>`  after refreshes, which are done via ajax. But I will add a comment in the referenced staoverflow answer to ask this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `onevent` attribute of JSF's `<f:ajax>` tag, that's used to perform AJAX tasks within a JSF application. Basically it specifies a JavaScript function that's called thrice: before AJAX call is sent, after AJAX response is received and after HTML DOM is updated. Exactly for this purpose PrimeFaces has split those callbacks into `onstart`, `onsuccess`, `oncomplete` and `onerror` respectively.

Not to be repetitive, you can find usage example in the answer to [How to re-execute javascript function after form reRender?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13085569/1820286).

Comment: Yes I know, though this would mean that I need to edit every `Ajax`-call on my page. As I stated in my question, I'm searching for a way to avoid this. E.g.: an `f:event` that is triggered upon every `Ajax-call` on the page.

Comment: In this case you could investigate jsf.js and build up several JS helper functions to send ajax requests not via tags, but via JavaScript.

Comment: Hmm will consider it, there's no default `JSF`-way so to speak?

Comment: No way that I know of. But it's definitely worth investigating the programmatic JS approach for your reason.