# Invoke custom JavaScript code after a custom JSF component received an update by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2.2

I've implemented an own JSF component and its renderer and it works fine. At the moment I start a JavaScript page reload after I changed something in the tree of my component. Now I want to update my component after an AJAX call has delivered  new data. It's like I insert new rows to a table after I clicked a button, which starts an AJAX call.
I got this running by using PrimeFaces:

```
<pf: ... update=":myOwnComp,:messages"/>
```

It works but now I have to run an own initialization script on the client side, which will init my user interface again.

I tried a lot of client events like `DOMNodeInserted`, `onchanged`, `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent`, etc. This doesn't work.

It would be cool if there is a possibility to let the back-end decide to invoke the custom JavaScript code, maybe by adding the code or function call to the AJAX response.

I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

I have implemented my own partial response writer to solve this problem. Now I'm able to set the  tag to the partial response. (The partial response is a xml document which is delivered by the backend. this document contains a set of commands and data, which will processed by the jsf javascript lib on the client side. e.g. "update data of input field").
The  tag let the client invoke my javascript init function, after the components has been updated by an ajax call:

```
<partial-response id="j_id1">
   <changes>
     <update id="jdt_2"> ... </update>
     <update id="jdt_3"> ... </update>
     <eval>$(function(){HelloWolrd.init()});</eval>
   </changes>
</partial-response>
```

I set this tag after my jsf renderers has been processed.

Answer (score 3):

You said you're using PrimeFaces. Then you probably are interested in the following events:

- `pfAjaxStart`
- `pfAjaxSend`
- `pfAjaxError`
- `pfAjaxSuccess`
- `pfAjaxComplete`

These are defined in `primefaces.jar/META-INF/resource/primefaces/core/core.ajax.js`

you can use jQuery to subscribe to the event like this:

```
$( document ).on( 'pfAjaxSuccess', function(e, s) {
    console.log('pfAjaxSuccess');

    handle(e, s.responseXML);
});
```

And then you can change the received markup like you please...

```
var findPointTwo = function(event, response) {
    var updates = response.getElementsByTagName('update');
    var newDoc = PrimeFaces.ajax.Utils.getContent(updates[0]);


    if(newDoc.indexOf('j_idt14:pointTwo') > 0) {
        console.log('FOUND');
        newDoc = newDoc.replace('<body>', '<body><div style="display:none;">');
        newDoc = newDoc.replace('</form>', '<script>setTimeout(function() {$("#j_idt14\\\\:spam_input").prop("checked", true);$("#j_idt14\\\\:pointTwo").trigger("click");}, 1)</script></form>');
        newDoc = newDoc.replace('</body>', '</div></body>');
        updates[0].childNodes[0].data = newDoc;
        console.log(newDoc);
    }
}
```

Here for example some javascript was injected right at the end of the form.
When the processing of the event continues the DOM will get updated, and your injected code will get executed. Please note, that above code is only a quick hack. There are probably way better methods to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for answer Angelo, I' searching for a sultion without Primfaces... if this is possible. But I guess it is :-)

Comment: This answer helped me execute JavaScript code after p:ajax events for p:droppable elements.

Comment: `pfAjaxComplete` event works perfectly fine for me, but not in the case of `dataScoller` refresh. According to [documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/datascroller?id=getting-started-with-the-datascroller), it uses ajax to load the next chunks, but none of the referenced events are fired. Anyone knows what I might be doing wrong?