# JSF $(document).ajaxComplete not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf

why is .ajaxComplete(...) etc. not working when I want to use it in JSF?

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

is there a worksround to get the **global ajax listener running in jquery (used by jsf)** (I want to update e.g. the size of the navigation bar when additional content is loaded)?

i want to execute JS-Code (in JSF) with

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() { //DOSTUFF// });
```

Comment: What error do you face? Is there any error in console?

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528270/how-is-ajax-request-handled-in-jsf-2-0